# How to validate the select drop-down menu with express-validator in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js, express-validator

So this is the dropdown in handelbar page and I want to validate it with express-validator.
Condition to be fulfilled: If the selected option is not "Done" then I want send the error above the select field in handlebar as "Select Done to proceed".

```
<select name="sources" id="{{commonID}}" class="custom-select sources" placeholder="{{status}}">
      <option value="0">In Progress</option>
      <option value="1">Done</option>
      <option value="2">Rejected</option>
    </select>
```

How can achieve that?
Help please!!!